# JavaScript function only selects first checkbox when told to pre-select more

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function that dynamically creates checkbox elements when some value from a select box is selected. To verify if a checkbox is checked or not, from PHP I send a variable.

For example: `var_id=1,2,3,5`. I use `jQuery.inArray`, but I have checked only first checkbox checked from list of five.

This is the function that creates the lis of checkboxes:

```
function outcheckboxes(_id, _text, var_id) {
  (function($){
    var topicContainer = jQuery('#classificationss_id');

    topicContainer.append(
        $('<li />')
        .addClass('checkboxclassid')
        .append(
            $('<input />', {
            id:      'classid' + _id,
            name:    'classid[]',
            value:   _id,
            type:    'checkbox',
            checked: !$.inArray(_id, var_id)
            })                                      
        )
        .append(
            $('<label />', {
            'for':  'classid' + _id
            }).text( _text)
            )
        )
    })(jQuery)
}
```

I call the function `outcheckboxes` from an other function :

```
function Classifications(obj_parent, obj_this, obj_child, var_id) {

        var catalog_id = jQuery("#"+obj_parent).selectedValues()[0];
        jQuery("#classificationss_id").children().remove();
        jQuery("#"+obj_this).children().remove();
        jQuery("#"+obj_child).children().remove();


        if(catalog_id>0){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "../index.php",
                data : "option=com_namecat&view=lists&format=raw&list=classifications&id=" + catalog_id,
                dataType : "xml",
                success : function(xml) {
                    var _id = "";
                    var _text = "";

                    jQuery(xml).find("row").each( function() {
                        _id = jQuery(this).find("id").text();
                        _text = jQuery(this).find("text").text();
                        jQuery("#"+obj_this).addOption(_id, _text );

                        outcheckboxes(_id,_text,var_id);

                    });
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Presumably you're aware of the `$` shorthand?

Comment: Tried `alert()`-ing the value of `var_id.join(', ')`?

Comment: With $ shorthand I have error in browser. I use jquery in Joomla framework and only with jQuery work normal. I obtain `var_id.join is not a function`

Comment: What is `var_id` then? I thought it was an `Array`, which has the built in function `join`

Comment: `var_id` is a string from database. This is a list of id-s delimited by `,` . I send `var_id` from joomla with event `onchange`. This is the code from php `<?php echo JHTML::_('Select.genericlist',$this->catalogs,"catalog_id",'onchange="updateClassifications(\'catalog_id\',\'classification_id\',1, \''.$this->data->classification_id.'\')"',"catalog_id","catalog_name", $this->data->catalog_id); ?>`

Comment: `$this->data->classification_id` is `var_id`

Comment: How are you injecting var_id into your javascript? I think that's what's causing you the problem. Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67sgX/) to see what I mean.

Comment: In DB I have this string `5,10,11`. Above, I have updated the code. With alert(var_id), I see `5,10,11`.

Comment: Still not enough code. Where's the `success : function(xml) {` coming from? I need the context of that

Comment: Hi Eric, above I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one, you should be writing your code like this:

#### EDIT:

Added shorthand

```
(function($) {
    $('<li />')
        .addClass('checkboxclassid')
        .append(
            $('<input />', {
                id:      'classid' + _id,
                name:    'classtype[]',
                value:   _id,
                type:    'checkbox',
                checked: !$.inArray(_id, var_id) 
            })                                      
        )
        .append(
            $('<label />', {
                'for':  'classid' + _id
            }).text( _text)
        )
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: With `$` shorthand I have error in browser. I use jquery in Joomla framework and only with `jQuery` work normal.

Comment: @Alexandru: I've modified the code so that the `$` shorthand will work with joomla.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I have tried with modified code but the result is same. Maybe problem is in `var_id`. with alert a can see for example `4,5,10`. Therefore the checkboxses with id `4`, `5` and `10` must be checked, but I have checked only the checkbox with id `4`.